# How to get all numbers from list which are located at multiple of 3 index

Tags: python, list, indexing, slice

How to get all numbers from list which are located at multiple of 3 index
for example

```
li=['ab','ha','kj','kr','op','io']
```

i need

```
['kj','io']
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `slicing` on list where `[2::3]` means start from 2nd index(indices start from 0 in python) and get every 3rd element

```
print(li[2::3])
```

Output:

```
['kj','io']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for index,i in enumerate(li):
    index = index+1
    if index % 3 == 0: print(i)
```